Can you suggest a real-world analogy for nanophysics, specifically focusing on van der Waals forces, that is practical and suitable for a workshop?
I’m preparing a workshop on the evolution of physics, focusing on nano topics, particularly van der Waals forces. My idea is to simulate the interaction between two hydrogen atoms using C programming to graph how forces vary with their distance. While I find this concept interesting, could you advise if there are alternative simulations or concepts that would be more suitable and tangible for this workshop?
Thank you for your time and suggestions!"

You will be better to ask the community where you publish your studies.
